# PowerPoint slide resolution? (Optimizing video playback)

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

In PowerPoint 2007, there seems to be no way of changing the resolution slide (only the aspect ratio and the output resolution can be chnaged?).

If this is the case, then how do I optimize an inserted video for playback using an HD projector?

Can I simply insert a video at high resolution and scale it down to fit the slide? Will these extra pixels come to use if the output resolution is high?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just scale the video according to the slide, it will automatically scale. I just tried it and was able to show a 1080p video. If you want to have wide screen, [check out this downloadable Powerpoint Presentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/widescreen-presentation-TC010176930.aspx).

If that doesn't work, consider using a clickable image instead which would open an external video.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps, on the Slide Show tab, there's the option to run the presentation at Current Resolution (ie, whatever your Windows video settings dictate) or at some other resolution you choose.
PPT kicks the display into the rez you pick at the beginning of the show, then returns it to the previous value when the show ends.